# Adding a new listem to a list, and want to append to the end even if empty

Tags: jquery

Currently my DOM looks like:

```
<ol id="abc">

</ol>
```

Using ajax, I am appending to the last item in the list.

```
$("#abc li:last").after(newHtml)
```

This works if there is a li in the ol.

How can I get this same behaviour when the ol is empty initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#abc").append(newHtml)`

[`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) Simple stuff. Appends always appends it as the last child of an element.

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/cZjsG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

simple append does it, if I understand correctly

```
$("#abc").append(newLIHtml);
```